# MessageAwareListener Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds (AS 5.1 + ESB 4.10)

Tags: jboss5.x, jbpm, jboss-esb

I have a problem with my ESB archives. I'm porting ESB projects from ESB server 4.4 to ESB 4.10 integrated in Jboss AS 5.1.0. I had built projects with right Runtime Environment 5.1. When the server started I have periodic Warnings. I had seen more topics in jboss esb community but no one resolve the problem. I have tried to increase my connection pool in jboss-esb.properties but no change. Then an extract-log:

```
 17:19:40,559 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:19:41,565 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 8000 milliseconds
 17:19:49,568 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:19:50,582 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 16000 milliseconds
 17:20:06,584 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:20:07,592 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:20:39,594 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:20:40,603 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:21:12,617 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:21:13,639 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:21:45,641 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:21:46,650 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:22:18,652 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:22:19,662 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:22:51,664 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:22:52,672 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:23:24,674 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:23:25,683 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:23:57,684 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:23:58,692 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:24:30,694 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:24:31,701 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:25:03,703 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:25:04,711 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:25:36,713 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:25:37,720 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:26:09,722 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:26:10,729 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:26:42,731 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:26:43,738 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:27:15,740 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:27:16,747 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
 17:27:48,749 INFO  [MessageAwareListener] State reached : false
 17:27:49,756 WARN  [MessageAwareListener] Error processing courier, backing off for 32000 milliseconds
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Best regards